# Extra information in `loading` substate

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember app. In a given route, I have a handcrafted model that is not loaded immediately. Thus, I hand it over as a promise:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return MyModel.create().promise();
  }
})
```

Don't worry too much about how `MyModel` works. The important bit is that it returns an RSVP promise.

As a result, Ember transitions to a `loading` route. There, I have a template that renders correctly showing a spinner, transitioning to the correct route once the promise is resolved.

My question is: **how can I show real progress?** `MyModel` does something relatively complex, with several steps, and I would like to show actual progress on these steps. Instead of a stateless spinner, I would like to show stateful progress. `MyModel` (or rather, its promises) knows about its progress, but I don't know how to communicate it down to the template.

I implemented a route and a controller for this loading state. Both load correctly, but neither seems to have access to anything that may help here. In fact, I can't see that RSVP promises even have a progress handler, like other libraries do. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Route`'s `controllerFor` function to access other controllers.

So in your main route you can use `this.controllerFor('loading')` to get the `LoadingController` and set properties on it that way.

Your `model` hook could look something like this:

```
model: function() {
  var loadingController = this.controllerFor('loading');
  loadingController.set('progress', 0);

  var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Ember.run.later(loadingController, 'set', 'progress', 10, 1000);
    Ember.run.later(loadingController, 'set', 'progress', 30, 1300);
    Ember.run.later(loadingController, 'set', 'progress', 50, 1800);
    Ember.run.later(loadingController, 'set', 'progress', 70, 2300);
    Ember.run.later(loadingController, 'set', 'progress', 90, 3300);
    Ember.run.later(loadingController, 'set', 'progress', 100, 4000);
    Ember.run.later(null, resolve, [1,2,3], 4000);
  });

  loadingController.set('promise', promise);
  return promise;
}
```

I've created a [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sidafet/9/edit?html,js,output) that gives an example of this.

Comment: That seems to work. One detail: I had to refer to the controller as 'my-model.loading', as opposed to just 'loading', or it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yep thats ok - I take it your route is called 'my-model' for example? The example I gave demonstrated it for the top level (e.g. application) route. You might have to access `my-model.loading` and someone else in their project might have to access `groups.people.loading`.. Just depends where the particular `loading` controller is for the current route you're using.